# React + Spring | Authentication always fails with axios.post but it is working with axios.get

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, axios

I have an Authentication filter in my rest API.

SecuritfyConfig:

```
@Autowired
private CustomTokenAuthentication authProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
{
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.cors().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
}
```

CustomTokenAuthentication:

```
EmployeeService employeeService;
public CustomTokenAuthentication(EmployeeService employeeService)
{
    this.employeeService = employeeService;
}

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException
{

    String name = authentication.getName();
    String sessionKey = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    System.out.println(name + " | " + sessionKey);

    if(employeeService.checkSessionKey(sessionKey))
    {
        System.out.println("access granted");
        // use the credentials
        // and authenticate against the third-party system
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, sessionKey, new ArrayList<>());
    } else
    {
        System.out.println("access not granted");
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication)
{
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
```

Now if I want to access some Data from the frontend I use this Axios Command:

```
axios.get("https://localhost:8443/components",  {
  auth: {
    username: "user",
    password: this.getCookie("session_key")
  },})
    .then(response => {
      const components = response.data;
      this.setState({components})
    })
```

This axios.get works fine. If I try the same with axios.post I doesn't work. I know that the post has another Syntax then the Get but it still does not work:

```
    axios.post('https://localhost:8443/filter', {
          node: this.state.filterNodes,
          service: this.state.filterServices,
          component: this.state.filterComponents
        },
  {
    auth: {
      username: 'user',
      password: this.getCookie("session_key")
    }
    }).then(response => {
      const applications = response.data;
      this.setState({applications})
    })
```

I get this error in my Console:

```
POST https://localhost:8443/filter 401
```

When I ignore this specific URL in the Config it works fine. But it should also go throught Authentication.

Comment: try moving auth object to the first object. ```axios.post(..., {auth: ..., node: ..., service: ...})```

Comment: @JuniusL. I now have it like this:
    axios.post('https://localhost:8443/filter', {
          auth: {
            username: 'user',
            password: this.getCookie("rdmonitoring_session_key")
          },
          node: this.state.filterNodes,
          service: this.state.filterServices,
          component: this.state.filterComponents
        }).then(response => {
      const applications = response.data;
      this.setState({applications})
    })

It still doesn't work - same error....

Comment: try ```axios.post(..., {node: ..., service: ...}, {params: auth: {...}})```

Comment: @JuniusL. I had to set another {after params: and a } after the auth block that the Syntax worked. Unfortunately I still get an 401 error....

Comment: @JuniusL. You got another hint for me ?